# Windows 2008 server as guest in VMWare: can't ping

Tags: vmware, windows-server-2008, ping, gateway

I can't ping the guest from the host.

Doing an `ipconfig`, it seems that there is no default gateway.

Comment: doh!!!!! windows firewall was on!  Thanks for all the comments, though.

Comment: you should post that as an answer then so this shows up as being solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows firewall was on!! now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a VMWare problem, the only way I could see it being a problem is with a NIC setting issue. Make sure that the NIC is set to Eth0 in the VM settings.

Other than this, you may want to check your TCP/IP settings on the guest machine to make sure that they are set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Check IP addresses (DHCP) and VMware Network adapter settings.

If you can't find anything suspicious, include all that info in your post.