# cannot ping virtual servers on Hyper-V Manager

Tags: windows-10

I am using Hyper-V Manger on Windows 10 pro to create 3 virtual servers. One is my AD, while others are for other application. I had joined all to the Domain and have connected all using the virtual switch. I could map drives, folders and share files among them. It was working perfectly before.

Recently, I tried to copy a file form one system to another and discovered that the network could not be found. I tried pinging the server but was getting destination unreachable. I have tried checking everything that could be responsible but none worked.

Please, I need help in resolving this issue.

Thanks

Emeka

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 2008 server as guest in VMWare: can't ping](https://superuser.com/questions/207506/windows-2008-server-as-guest-in-vmware-cant-ping)

Answer (score 1):

Check "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings"  and allow file and printer sharing and turn on password protection.